# Can the value in [name^="value"] be a variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm hoping to use this selector here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

It says it selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

Does this purely apply to matching strings, or can a variable with a value matching the string be used in the place of "value"?

Comment: Selectors are strings. You can create that string from whatever you want.

Comment: Step 1 should be try it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a variable as value. Why not construct the selector?

```
$('[name^="' + value + '"]')
```

Comment: it's ... unbelievable!